# Jackson Parser To Java Object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson to parse object. sometime I need list of objects.

when I am using like this its working

```
 List<MyObject> mapper.readValue(file , new TypeReference<MyObject>() {})
```

but when I am using it like this its not working

```
public class JsonMocksRepository<T>{

    public  T getObject() throws Exception{

        return mapper.readValue(file ,new TypeReference<T>());
    }
}
```

What I need to do ?
Basically I want to use generics to get the right class

Comment: "Not working" is not a good enough description of the error. Please explaing what errors or exceptions you get. A complete stacktrace if helpful if you throw an exception.

Comment: You are right sorry .
Its working but , instead of returning list of object he returns List of LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of type erasure. There is no information about the actual type represented by T available at runtime, so your `TypeReference` will be effectively be simply `TypeReference<Object>`.

If you want a generic instance of `JsonMocksRepository`, you will need to inject the `TypeReference` at construction time:

```
public class JsonMocksRepository<T>{
  private final TypeReference<T> typeRef;

  public JsonMocksRepository(TypeReference<T> typeRef) {
    this.typeRef = typeRef;
  }

  public T getObject() throws Exception{
    return mapper.readValue(file, typeRef);
  }
}
```