# Parse JSON to java object when same field name occur in nested JSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, gson

Below is my JSON:

```
{
  "time":{
    "date":{
      "year":2017,
      "month":3,
      "day":12
     },
    "time":{
      "hour":10,
      "minute":42,
      "second":42,
      "nano":810000000
     }
   },
"name":"Jon",
"message":{
"product":"orange"
"price":2000
}
}
```

'time' field has a nested 'time' field. How can I parse this using jackson to java object. Can anyone please tell me the correct method?

Comment: Parse to a POJO or a Map? You'll easily find 2000+ answers for both here on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503471/jackson-parsing-for-json-object-inside-json) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29227394/jackson-parser-to-java-object)) or [in a source of your choice](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=jackson+parse+json+to+java+object).

Comment: I found a lot of answers but i did not find any to include "same name nested field" that converts JSON to POJO

Comment: Ok, sorry, i didn't understand you only want the inner `time` property. You can just parse everything to a JsonNode, get the inner Property as JsonNode and parse that to your POJO (see my answer).

Comment: In case you fall in other `JSON` structure you can always generate `POJO` model using online tools like it is described in this question: [Array of JSON Object to Java POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55248523/array-of-json-object-to-java-pojo/55249189#55249189)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create classes like these:

```
class JavaObject {
    private TimeObject time;
    private String name;
    //other fields
    //getters and setters
}

class TimeObject {
    private Date date;
    private Time time;
    //getters and setters
}

class Date {
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;
    //getters and setters
}

class Time {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;
    private long nano;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Once done, you can use `Jackson` to deserialize the `json` String into `JavaObject` object, e.g.:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JavaObject javaObject = objectMapper.readValue("{\n" + 
        "  \"time\":{\n" + 
        "    \"date\":{\n" + 
        "      \"year\":2017,\n" + 
        "      \"month\":3,\n" + 
        "      \"day\":12\n" + 
        "     },\n" + 
        "    \"time\":{\n" + 
        "      \"hour\":10,\n" + 
        "      \"minute\":42,\n" + 
        "      \"second\":42,\n" + 
        "      \"nano\":810000000\n" + 
        "     }\n" + 
        "   },\n" + 
        "\"name\":\"Jon\"}", JavaObject.class);
System.out.println(javaObject);
```

Comment: If they only need the data from the inner `time` prop, this seems like a lot of overhead. Or did i get the requirements wrong?

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you help me with one more thing. Sometimes the time field comes with hour, minute, second separately and sometimes it comes in string like "10:42:42:810000000" directly. In that case how can i create Time class?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the inner `time` object, you could do this in a quick way:

```
// your POJO class
// (public fields sould be private with getter & setter, of course)

public class Pojo {
    public int hour;
    public int minute;
    public int second;
    public long nano;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + ":" + nano;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
//your json string
String jsonString = "{\"time\":{\"date\":{\"year\":2017,\"month\":3,\"day\":12},"
                + "\"time\":{\"hour\":10,\"minute\":42,\"second\":42,\"nano\":810000000}},"
                + "\"name\":\"Jon\",\"message\":{\"product\":\"orange\",\"price\":2000}}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonRoot = mapper.readTree(jsonString); //parse string to JsonNode
Pojo pojo = mapper.treeToValue(jsonRoot.at("/time/time"), Pojo.class); //create Pojo instance from inner time object
System.out.println(pojo); //see if it worked
```

This prints:

```
10:42:42:810000000
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you help me with one more thing. Sometimes the time field comes with hour, minute, second separately and sometimes it comes in string like "10:42:42:810000000" directly. In that case how can i parse it?

Comment: @user812142 I don't really understand your question. The `10:42:42:810000000` is just a string that is constructed in the `toString()` method of the POJO. I only added it to show you an output that proves the data is there. If your Json doesn't contain `minute` or `hour`, those values will not be set (and left to default, so `0` in this case, but you could change that).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jackson library](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

```
ObjectMapper jsonMapper= new ObjectMapper();
YourCorrespondingObject object = jsonMapper.readValue("your json as string...", YourCorrespondingObject.class);
```

it's easier first to build your object, populate it, and convert to string, to make sure it equals your existing string, like:

```
String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
```